# Erro ao iniciar Tomcat 9 como serviço

Tags: java, tomcat

Estou com um problema para iniciar o Tomcat service. Quando tento iniciar o serviço, algum problema acontece e ele não é inicializado.

O log na `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs` é o seguinte:

```
[2015-12-12 17:34:58] [info]  [ 3476] Running 'FunctionsHandler' Service...
[2015-12-12 17:34:58] [info]  [ 4076] Starting service...
[2015-12-12 17:34:59] [error] [ 2236] FindClass org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap failed
[2015-12-12 17:34:59] [error] [ 4076] Failed to start Java
[2015-12-12 17:34:59] [error] [ 4076] ServiceStart returned 4
[2015-12-12 17:34:59] [info]  [ 3476] Run service finished.
[2015-12-12 17:34:59] [info]  [ 3476] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

A variável `JAVA_HOME` já está definida.

Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro não é especificamente da versão 9, não é novo, é por conta do Tomcat não ter detectado ou configurado corretamente o classpath para o `apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1/bin/boostrap.jar` e `apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1/bin/tomcat-juli.jar`.

Uma outra possivel situação é que também não tenha encontrado o caminho `(JAVA_HOME)` para a JVM, assim causando a falha ao tentar subir o web container `(Tomcat)`.

Você pode alterar seguindo as propriedades do serviço do Tomcat no Windows.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ref: http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2014/01/tomcat-7-findclass-orgapachecatalinasta.html

Comment: Pensei já ter definido a variável `JAVA_HOME`, mas como estava montando um ambiente novo, fiz tudo do zero e acabei por definir ela apontando pra pasta destino do JRE, e não do JDK. Depois de revisar, encontrei as variáveis, encontrei o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Galera tive o mesmo problema. Para resolver, eu abri o Apache Tomcat, fui em *Properties* e na aba *Startup* alterei o `Mode` de `jvm` para `java`. Depois disso o serviço iniciou corretamente.